# how to export bookmarks from Silk web browser without rooting?

Tags: browser, amazon-kindle-fire, bookmarks, export

I would like to export my Silk browser bookmarks, ideally to an HTML file.  Amazon has apparently made it impossible to export bookmarks from its Silk web browser on Kindle Fire.

Searching on StackExchange, I note several old recommendations to download certain apps in order to export bookmarks from Chrome or Firefox, and recommendations to root the Kindle.  I would rather not root the Kindle as I am not particularly tech-savvy and my connection to Amazon via the Kindle is important to me right now.

I have enabled the Google Play Store.  Is my best bet to download some app from there, or is there another way I can export Silk bookmarks without possibly messing up my ability to access Amazon content?